# setting back the cursor/carat at the end of the appended string in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So to reproduce the issue, here's a fiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/QRgE9/1/

Type in the following string into the box: Hello @An

And then make a selection from the dropdown.

You can see that after you've made the selection the cursor is no where to be found and user have to click again on the div. How do I make it such that the cursor blinks (doesn't loses it's focus) after I made the selection? I know facebook can do this just fine.. so I think I am missing something.

Also the cursor is not always appended at the end of the string. If the case is I am inserting this in the middle of the string, then the cursor should start again at the middle of the string.

Here's the code that is triggered when the user made a selection:

```
$(".display_box").live("mousedown",function(event) 
    {
        $("#friendsList").hide();
        selRange = saveSelection();
        var startOffset = selRange.startOffset;
        var endOffset = selRange.endOffset;

        var username = $(this).attr('title');
        var currentContent = $("#recommendTextArea").html();
        var E ="<span contenteditable='false' title=\"" + username + "\">"+ username + "</span> ";
        var newContent = currentContent.replace(word, E); //replacing @abc to users real name 
        $("#recommendTextArea").html(newContent);

        selRange.setStart($("#recommendTextArea")[0].childNodes[0], startOffset);
        selRange.setEnd($("#recommendTextArea")[0].childNodes[0], endOffset);
        restoreSelection(selRange);
        event.preventDefault();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the lost focus issue, bind the event handler with the `click` instead of a `mousedown` and then set the focus manually:

```
$(".display_box").live("click",function(event) /* <--- this was changed */
{
    $("#friendsList").hide();
    selRange = saveSelection();
    var startOffset = selRange.startOffset;
    var endOffset = selRange.endOffset;

    var username = $(this).attr('title');
    var currentContent = $("#recommendTextArea").html();
    var E ="<span contenteditable='false' title=\"" + username + "\">"+ username + "</span> ";
    var newContent = currentContent.replace(word, E); //replacing @abc to users real name 
    $("#recommendTextArea").html(newContent).focus(); /* <--- this was added */

    selRange.setStart($("#recommendTextArea")[0].childNodes[0], startOffset);
    selRange.setEnd($("#recommendTextArea")[0].childNodes[0], endOffset);
    restoreSelection(selRange);
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: I tried changing that however, the position of the cursor is always wrong

Comment: I think you should set the cursor position to `start`, i.e., set `selRange` start and end to `start` instead of `startOffset` and `endOffset`. It might need a bit more tweaking, but it generally worked when I tried it on your fiddle.

Comment: can you post your modified fiddle

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was in the wrong direction and I can't get this to work properly. However, the problem is not selection start/end, but the object in which selection resides. When you add `span` to your `div`, your div gets children: `Text', `HTMLSpanElement` and `Text'. You want to position your caret at position 0 in the second `Text` object. Different browsers behave differently here (i.e., SeaMonkey gets another `HTMLBRElement` at the end; Chrome ignored mu focusing,...), so it'll need a lot more time than I can afford. I hope this will at least send you in the right direction.

Comment: I tried getting the index of the new part of text, i.e., the index of the `Text` child that is created right after your new span. If we had that index as `idx` variable, your selection would be something like `selRange.setStart($("#recommendTextArea")[0].childNodes[idx], 0); selRange.setEnd($("#recommendTextArea")[0].childNodes[idx], 0);`. But, since I couldn't get this to work, I can give you no fiddle.